# Error in visualize splines logistic regression with ns in R

Tags: r, spline, rsm

I have this error when I want to visualize splines logistic regression with `ns`:

```
data <- read.table("e:/data_logistic.txt",　header = TRUE)

dd <- datadist(data)

options(datadist = "dd")

model <- lrm(formula = P_A ~ ns(HEIGHT, 4), data = data, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)

p1 <- ggplot(Predict(model, HEIGHT))

Error in quantile.default(x[!outside], knots) : missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
```

[image]

When I use `rcs` (from rsm package) instead of `ns` (from spines package) I have not any problem. I want to use `ns` method. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can we have a [mcve] please? How many unique values of `HEIGHT` do you have?

Comment: The data has 96 observations, 32 presence points and 64 absence points. almost 98% are unique values.

Comment: OK, then my only guess doesn't work.  We'll definitely need the example data.

Comment: Could you explain more about example data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: even `summary(data$HEIGHT)` would probably help.

Comment: I can at least replicate the problem with `set.seed(101); data <- data.frame(HEIGHT = c(runif(95, 150, 650), 1500), P_A = sample(0:1, size = 96, replace = TRUE))`

Comment: Thank you so much but I still have this error.

Comment: This is clearly using the "rms" package. Spelling is crucially important.

Comment: The error is coming from `rms::Predict`. I guess the message is use `rms::rcs` rather than `splines::ns`. Was there any reason to assume that `rms::Predict` should work with `ns`? The rms functions are build to work together but not necessarily work with other packages.

Comment: You are right about it. I understand now